# How did Tibco BW HTTP Receiver accept a REST Web Service Request?

Tags: rest, tibco

How did Tibco BW HTTP Receiver accept a REST Web Service Request???
How to configure it??

How did Tibco BW expose a REST Web Service???

Now we are using Tibco BW5.9;

Thanks

Comment: There is new REST/JSON plugin available. That would help you.

Answer (score 2):

From a HTTP point of view, there is nothing special about REST requests. There are examples for how to receive and process REST requests in [rest4BW](http://windyroad.com.au/software/rest4bw/)

Answer (score 1):

Tibco rest/json plugin is just to parse to and from json and to invoke rest services

Check BW-REST for a complete restful web application, see it on http://nicosommi.com/?p=174